# how to group the data by some interval datetimes?

Tags: mysql, sql

**there are many devices and while using it will upload data every some seconds or minutes.**
**I want to get the sections of date-time that the device is in use**

```
 Id  date-time                                    value
 0  2021-07-08 14:46:46                       1
 1  2021-07-08 14:47:47                       5
 2  2021-07-08 14:48:48                       2
 3  2021-07-08 14:49:49                       4
 4  2021-07-08 15:30:01                       7
 5  2021-07-08 15:30:46                       4
 6  2021-07-08 15:30:46                       4
 7  2021-07-08 15:50:04                       4
 8  2021-07-08 15:50:05                       6
```

can it be true that group the data by an interval?
let us consider `interval = 1 minutes`
then group the data which the minus of the two date-time is more than 1 minutes.
then **Id=0 or Id=1 or Id=2 or Id=3** is one group and **Id=4 and Id=5 and Id=6 and Id=7 and Id=8** is another group

what I want is the group is a nearly date-time.

If the difference between two records is more than 1 minute then they are in two groups. If not they are in the same groups.

which means in the same group time1 will be smaller than 1 minutes to one of the other time.

**If the time difference is 1 or 10 minutes larger than the previous record it will belong to a new groups**

and I am using MYSQL

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: If available, you can use `datetime_trunc` or alike to truncate timestamp variables up to desired level and group by them. Alternatively, you may use `strftime` or alike to convert timestamps into strings of desired format.  For example, if you group by strings of format `%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M`, then each group would share a same up to the minute.

Comment: @KotaMori but what matters is the group of the date-time boundary and the hours is not sure. may be it is only 3 minutes for use(the device is open) or may it is 5 hours 30minutes. so the group may be not the same. I do not quite understand what you say the strings of format . they can be same and not matters.

Comment: @打玻璃 You need to define criteria on how close records need to be within the same group.  For example, one may consider ID=4,5,6 in a same group, because they are the same up to minutes, or may separate ID=4 and ID=5,6.  Which makes sense to you, and why?

Comment: @KotaMori If two records's date-time 's time difference let me say is lower than `10 minutes` then it is in the same group. for example,ID=4,5,6 the time difference is smaller than 10 minutes so all is in one group. but ID=4 compare to ID=3 it is 16 minutes so it is in another group.

Comment: Okay, can you update the question that if the time difference from the previous is larger than 10 minutes then this recors should belong to a new group. This way, this question becomes a straightforward sql question and many people can help.  It will be helpful to specify which sql software you use because the sytax varies across the dialects al lot.

Comment: @KotaMori I have updated it .pls check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can use `lag` window function to obtain previous date_time.
- One way to calculate the time difference in seconds is to convert timestamp type to integer by `unix_timestamp` function.
- Make a `newgroup` flag which equals one if and only if the difference from the previous record is larger than 60*10 seconds (10 minutes).
- Cumulative sum of `newgroup` would become the section group ID.

```sql
with tmp AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    coalesce(unix_timestamp(date_time) - unix_timestamp(lag(date_time) over (ORDER BY date_time)), 0) > 60*10 AS newgroup
  FROM
    tbl
)
,tmp2 AS (
  SELECT 
    *,
    sum(newgroup) over (ORDER BY date_time) AS groupid 
  FROM
    tmp 
)
SELECT * FROM tmp2
```

This query would get:

```
    id   date_time  value   newgroup    groupid
    0   2021-07-08 14:46:46 1   0   0
    1   2021-07-08 14:47:47 5   0   0
    2   2021-07-08 14:48:48 2   0   0
    3   2021-07-08 14:49:49 4   0   0
    4   2021-07-08 15:30:01 7   1   1
    5   2021-07-08 15:30:46 4   0   1
    6   2021-07-08 15:30:46 4   0   1
    7   2021-07-08 15:50:04 4   1   2
    8   2021-07-08 15:50:05 6   0   2
```

Comment: Thank you @Kota Mori but id=0 compare to id=7 is smaller than 10 minutes right? and they have different groupid

Comment: and what it means that newgroup=0 or newgroup=1?

Comment: and what about in mssql?

Comment: can I give you 50 extra bounty now?

Comment: id=0 and id=7 differ by about 50 minutes.  And newgroup is a variable that equals 1 if this record should be in a different group than the previous record. mssql version would be a bit different but not that much. Try searching for the equivalent functions on mssql.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . It sounds like you are looking for *gaps* to defines groups that are related, and the gaps are determined by the interval.

In pseudo-SQL, this might look like:

```
select min(date_time), max(date_time), count(*), avg(value)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_date_time > date_time - interval '1 minute' then 0 else 1 end) over (order by date_time) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(date_time) over (order by date_time) as prev_date_time
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by grp;
```

Comment: there are some devices which will upload data every some seconds such as 30s while in use or open. and I want to get the section of data-time that the device is in use.

Comment: so why you select the avg and min or max?

Comment: than you for your answer @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @打玻璃 . . . Those are arbitary.  Your question doesn't say what you want to do with the groups.